# Javascript prototypes methods vs. internal methods

Tags: javascript, prototype, function-prototypes

What is the difference between making a method using `prototype` and just creating it inside a function? E.g., what's the difference between `methodOne` and `methodTwo` below?

```
function myFunc() {
  this.methodOne = function () { console.log("First method.")};
}

myFunc.prototype.methodTwo = function () { console.log("Second method.")};
```

They seem to behave the same way:

```
var myFuncInstance = new myFunc();
myFuncInstance.methodOne();
myFuncInstance.methodTwo();
```

But my sense is that `methodTwo`, by accessing the `prototype` directly, is doing something a little different.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that every instance of `myFunc` **shares** the same single instance of `methodTwo`, but has its own instance of `methodOne`.

I.e.

```
var foo = new myFunc();
var bar = new myFunc();
foo.methodOne === bar.methodOne; // false
foo.methodTwo === bar.methodTwo; // true
```

Taking this a bit further, if you are creating 1000 `myFunc` instances, you are creating 1000 `methodOne` functions that all do the same thing. There still would be only one `methodTwo` function.

Answer (score 1):

With using the .prototype syntax you can add methods to existing objects. For example you can add a sum method to the array type using

Array.prototype.sum = function() {...}

Then use it as

var a = [1,2,3] and then doing a.sum()

With .prototype you can just keep on extending based on your needs just as you would in a class based language.

Comment: While what you say is correct, it doesn't really answer the question.